# Calculate a mean of pandas dataframe whose cells are list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have the following pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df= pd.DataFrame(np.nan, columns =["A","B","C"], index =np.arange(5))
df=df.astype(object)
for c in list(df):
    for i in df.index.values:
        df.at[i, c]=np.arange(5).tolist()
```

This results in df whose cells are numpy arrays

```
df
Out[16]: 
                 A                B                C
0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
2  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
3  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
4  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I would like to calculate the mean of the dataframe but it does not work as each cell is treated as a string. For example,

```
type(df.loc[0][0])
Out[19]: list
```

Thus, if I calculate its mean, it returns nan

```
df["Average"]= df.mean(axis=1)

df
Out[21]: 
                 A                B                C  Average
0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]      NaN
1  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]      NaN
2  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]      NaN
3  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]      NaN
4  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]      NaN
```

My question is, how would I convert this df back to numeric values that I can work with?

Comment: Define "mean" with respect to 3 lists.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the mean for each dataframe element (ie each list)? Thus 15 mean values?

Comment: @coldspeed The mean would be, for each row, `mean = sum(all_numerical_values_in_the_row)/ len (row) `

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas mean of list within dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708334/pandas-mean-of-list-within-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think idea convert values to columns is really good, because then is possible use pandas vectorized functions:

```
df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df[c].values.tolist()) for c in df.columns], 
                 axis=1, 
                 keys=df.columns)
df1.columns = ['{}{}'.format(i, j) for i, j in df1.columns]
print (df1)
   A0  A1  A2  A3  A4  B0  B1  B2  B3  B4  C0  C1  C2  C3  C4
0   0   1   2   3   4   0   1   2   3   4   0   1   2   3   4
1   0   1   2   3   4   0   1   2   3   4   0   1   2   3   4
2   0   1   2   3   4   0   1   2   3   4   0   1   2   3   4
3   0   1   2   3   4   0   1   2   3   4   0   1   2   3   4
4   0   1   2   3   4   0   1   2   3   4   0   1   2   3   4
```

But if need `mean` of all lists together:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.nan, columns =["A","B","C"], index =np.arange(5))
df=df.astype(object)
for c in list(df):
    for i in df.index.values:
        df.at[i, c]=np.arange(i+1).tolist()
print (df)
                 A                B                C
0              [0]              [0]              [0]
1           [0, 1]           [0, 1]           [0, 1]
2        [0, 1, 2]        [0, 1, 2]        [0, 1, 2]
3     [0, 1, 2, 3]     [0, 1, 2, 3]     [0, 1, 2, 3]
4  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

from itertools import chain
from statistics import mean
df['Average'] = [mean(list(chain.from_iterable(x))) for x in df.values.tolist()]
print (df)
                 A                B                C  Average
0              [0]              [0]              [0]      0.0
1           [0, 1]           [0, 1]           [0, 1]      0.5
2        [0, 1, 2]        [0, 1, 2]        [0, 1, 2]      1.0
3     [0, 1, 2, 3]     [0, 1, 2, 3]     [0, 1, 2, 3]      1.5
4  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]      2.0
```

EDIT:

If values are strings:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.nan, columns =["A","B","C"], index =np.arange(5))
df=df.astype(object)
for c in list(df):
    for i in df.index.values:
        df.at[i, c]=np.arange(5).tolist()

df=df.astype(str)
print (df)
                 A                B                C
0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
2  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
3  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
4  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

df1 = pd.concat([df[c].str.strip('[]').str.split(', ', expand=True) for c in df.columns], 
                 axis=1, 
                 keys=df.columns).astype(float)
df1.columns = ['{}{}'.format(i, j) for i, j in df1.columns]
df1["Average"]= df1.mean(axis=1)
print (df1)
    A0   A1   A2   A3   A4   B0   B1   B2   B3   B4   C0   C1   C2   C3   C4  \
0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0   
1  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0   
2  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0   
3  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0   
4  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0   

   Average  
0      2.0  
1      2.0  
2      2.0  
3      2.0  
4      2.0
```

Comment: Interesting approach but it does not seem to address the issue. For example, the following code snipped produces nan on the average column `df1["Average"]= df.mean(axis=1)`

Comment: @LiamdeBoeuf - If need last solution, I forget cast to numeric. Now it should working.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to restructure your dataframe as mentioned. But to work with what you have, assuming you want the mean of each element in the dataframe, you can try the `applymap` method.

```
df.applymap(np.mean)
```