# iterate through list of number in dataframes python

Tags: python

I have a list number data frame and I want to calculate the average using Python language
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYeIx.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas mean of list within dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708334/pandas-mean-of-list-within-dataframe)

Comment: You want to calculate the average within each semester, I suppose?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.apply` here with a lambda function.

```
df["Course Final Score"] = df["Course Final Score"].apply(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x))
```

Essentially your applying the function `sum(x)/len(x)` to every `x` in your column `"Course Final Score"`, i.e replacing the list with the sum of that list divided by the length of that list which will give you the mean.

**EDIT**

If your list contains a string of a list, you can use json to decode it as follows:

```
import json
df["Score"].apply(lambda x: sum(json.loads(x))/len(json.loads(x)))
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Does your list of Scores contain strings at any point?

Comment: I've edited a solution for if your scores are string values.

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '['

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '['

Comment: Okay so by the errors I'm assuming the entire list is a string, please consider showing more code in you question in future. I've edited again based on the information you have given me.

Comment: No problem, please consider accepting my answer if it has solved your problem.