# Calculate mean for lists stored in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, list

I have a dataframe which each "cell" is a list and I wish to calculate the mean of each "cell".

[image: here is an example of the dataframe , I wish to calculate the mean for sample 1 index 0,sample 1 index 1.....]

will appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71227572/2246849

Comment: `df['Sample1'] = df['Sample1'].apply(np.mean)` and `df['Sample2'] = df['Sample2'].apply(np.mean)`

Comment: @richardec `df.update(df[['Sample1', 'Sample2']].mean())` might also work - not checked

Comment: @JonClements indeed that works, and it's a much nicer solution! :)

Comment: @richardec nope - it doesn't... random saturday evening idea :p

Comment: `df.update(df[['Sample1', 'Sample2']].applymap(np.mean))` seems fine though

Comment: Is there a way not using the update method if I want to keep the lists , but still keep an elegant code?